# Using System Variables in Shiro Configuration

Tags: shiro

I like using a .ini configuration file for Shiro, however, I don't like the idea of storing the password in the shiro.ini file.

I know little about programmatic configuration, and I don't find much said about it on the documentation.

How can I retain the .ini file for setting authorization rules for instance, but store the password in an environment or system variables?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post, it should explain how you can interpolate your strings: 
https://stormpath.com/blog/string-interpolation-apache-shiro