Add System / Environment variable in shiro.ini
I´m defining environment variable in my docker compose file:
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.5
    container_name: keycloak_gixxshare
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm-export.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
      - KEYCLOAK_URL=http://192.168.178.93:9009/auth
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/realm-export.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm-export.json
    command:
      #- "start"
      - start-dev
      - --import-realm
      - --http-port=9009
      - --http-enabled=true
      - --http-relative-path=auth
     #command: 
     # -v start-dev --import-realm
    ports:
      - "9009:9009"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

I would like to use "KEYCLOAK_URL" in my shiro.ini, but this seems not working:
I´m trying:
[main]
#### General
keycloakUrl = ${KEYCLOAK_URL}

But I got this error message:

Unable to instantiate class [${KEYCLOAK_URL}] for object named
'keycloakUrl'.  Please ensure you've specified the fully qualified
class name correctly.

How can I solve this?
My dependencies:
<!-- Shiro Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-aspectj</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-lang</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>


Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981948/using-system-variables-in-shiro-configuration/55006366
